# How to share IORef state between two function invocations in Haskell when using IO?

Tags: haskell, shared-state, ioref

I'm trying to learn Haskell and I'm playing around with IORef to which I try to save and find records. My [code](https://github.com/johanhaleby/rps-haskell) looks something like this (note that I've chosen "String" as IORef type in this example only for convienence and briefty, in my actual code I'm using a record. And also ignore that I'm using a Set instead of a Map, I will change that):

```
module MyTest where

import           Data.IORef
import           Data.Set
import           Data.Foldable          (find)

type State = (Set String)
type IORefState = IORef State

saveStringToState :: IO IORefState -> String -> IO String
saveStringToState stateIO string = do
  state <- stateIO
  atomicModifyIORef
    state
    (\oldStrings ->
       let updatedStrings = insert string oldStrings
       in (updatedStrings, updatedStrings))
  stringsState <- readIORef state :: IO State
  putStrLn ("### saved: " ++ show stringsState)
  return string

findStringInState :: IO IORefState -> String -> IO (Maybe String)
findStringInState stateIO soughtString = do
  state <- stateIO :: IO IORefState
  strings <- readIORef state :: IO State
  putStrLn ("Looking for " ++ soughtString ++ " in: " ++ show strings)
  return $ find (== soughtString) strings

doStuff =
  let stateIO = newIORef empty
  in do saveStringToState stateIO "string1"
        findStringInState stateIO "string1"
```

What I want to achieve is to share the state (Set) between the two function calls so that `findStringInState` can return the `String` that I just inserted into the Set. But when I run the `doStuff` function I get this:

```
*MyTest> doStuff
### saved: fromList ["string1"]
Looking for string1 in: fromList []
Nothing
```

I've probably misunderstood something since I thought the IORef should indeed be the container for my state.

1. Why is this not working?
2. What can I do to make it work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems that you confused `IO IORefState` with `IORefState` (without `IO`), more generally, `IO a` with `a`.

In your case, the value of `IO IORefState` is *the action* `newIORef empty`, which represents "an action that creates a fresh new `IORef` from scratch".
By contrast, `IORefState` (without `IO`) is the right, *raw object* that you should share among the functions that use it (`saveStringToState`, and `findStringInState`).
Then, both `saveStringToState` and `findStringInState` separately call `newIORef empty`, i.e. each of them create a different `IORefState` object, which cannot be affected by the other.

To fix, you must call `newIORef empty` (as an `IO` action using `<-`) in `doStuff` function and share the `IORefState` created by `newIORef empty` instead of `IO IORefState`:

```
  saveStringToState :: IORefState -> String -> IO String
  ...

  findStringInState :: IORefState -> String -> IO (Maybe String)
  ...

  let stateIO = newIORef empty
  in do ioRef <- stateIO
        saveStringToState ioRef "string1"
        findStringInState ioRef "string1"
  -- Or, more simply:
  do ioRef <- newIORef empty
     saveStringToState ioRef "string1"
     findStringInState ioRef "string1"
```

In my opinion, the difference between `IO a` with `a` is similar to the difference between "a function object that returns a value typed as `a` (with some side effects)" and "just a raw value typed as `a`" in the other programming languages.